# Informix DB error

Tags: informix

I am updating couple of rows in a table in informix Database and I do not know what may be the cause of the error. 
Query:

```
UPDATE device
 SET name = 'Test_Destination'
WHERE pkid IN
  (SELECT d.pkid
    FROM numplan AS n 
    JOIN routepartition AS rp 
      ON rp.pkid = n.fkroutepartition 
    JOIN devicenumplanmap AS dnpm 
      ON dnpm.fknumplan = n.pkid 
    JOIN device AS d
      ON dnpm.fkdevice = d.pkid 
    JOIN routelist AS rl 
      ON rl.fkdevice = d.pkid 
    JOIN routegroup AS rg 
      ON rg.pkid = rl.fkroutegroup AND n.tkpatternusage = 5 
   WHERE d.name='SME_RL'
  );
```

The error message is:

```
Error: soapenv:ClientCould not update a row in the table.-346Could not update a row in the table.executeSQLUpdate
```

I tried to Google this error and couldn't get much information: it just says 'might be it occurred because of an unexpected error like hardware errors or locking conflicts in the Database'.

Not sure how to proceed as I don't  have any idea about the error. Do you find any kind of error in the query or any thoughts about this error?

Comment: As ever, it helps if you identify the version of the server that you are using, the platform it is running on, and sometimes the client API version too.  For example, one site that has something to say is IBM's support site: [IC73675: SQL ERROR -346/-240 FROM UPDATE/DELETE STATEMENT WHEN THE TABLE HAS A FUNCTIONAL INDEX](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC73675) -- shouting in the original.  It probably doesn't apply to you, but it might.  One possible source of the trouble is that you're selecting from `device` but also updating it; that might be a source of problems.

Comment: and is missing the second error code (ISAM code) . This code will give more information about the real problem. If're you using java, you can use the `SQLException.getNextException()`to get the next code or set the `APPENDISAM=TRUE` at your string connection . (check the JDBC [informix manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/search/jdbc?scope=SSGU8G_12.1.0&lang=en) for more reference)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Jonathan and ceinamart..I didn't get any ISAM error,that's the interesting part.Let me go through the manual.